# C - Code says head is undeclared - trying to insert node into linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Can someone point me in the right direction? The error says `head` is undeclared in this line: `newNode1 -> next = head;`

```
typedef struct _node {
    int data;
    struct _node *next;
} node_t;

typedef struct {
    node_t *head;
    node_t *tail;
} LL_t;

//Post: inserts node with data x into location i of list L
void spliceinto(LL_t *L, int x, int i) {
    node_t *newNode1 = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    newNode1->data = x;
    newNode1->next = NULL;
    if (i == 1) {
        newNode1->next = head;
        head = newNode1;
        return;
    }
    node_t *newNode2 = head;
    for (int j = 0; j < i - 2; i++) {
        newNode2 = newNode2 -> next;
    }
    newNode1->next = newNode2->next;
    newNode2->next = newNode1;
}
```

Comment: It's more likely the compiler saying that. The message is quite clear, think about it! And not adding spaces around the arrow-operator makes your code better readable.

Comment: Well, err.. looking at the code, it's err... undefined where it's referenced.

Comment: Ask yourself - where is the variable called `head` declared in your code?

Comment: Presumably, you meant 'L->head' ?

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
newNode1 -> next = L->head;
L->head = newNode1;
```

Take into account that the function is invalid. For example in general `newNode2->next` can be equal to NULL. As result this loop

```
for (int j = 0; j < i-2; i++){
    newNode2 = newNode2 -> next;
}
```

can have undefined behaviour when the number of nodes is less than i.

And there is a typo

```
for (int j = 0; j < i-2; i++){
                         ^^^^
```

There must be `j++`.

Also you  should remember to update `tail` in the function if  `tail` was changed.

Here is a demonstartive program that shows how the function can be written.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _node 
{
    int data;
    struct _node * next;
} node_t;

typedef struct 
{
    node_t * head;
    node_t * tail;
} LL_t;

void spliceinto( LL_t *ll, int i, int x )
{
    node_t *newNode = malloc( sizeof( node_t ) );

    if ( newNode != NULL )
    {
        newNode->data = x;

        if ( i == 1 || ll->head == NULL )
        {             
            newNode->next = ll->head;
            ll->head = newNode;
            if ( ll->head->next == NULL ) ll->tail = ll->head;
        }
        else
        {
            node_t *current = ll->head;
            for ( int j = 0; j < i - 2 && current->next != NULL; j++ )
            {
                current = current->next;
            }

            newNode->next = current->next;
            current->next = newNode;
            if ( newNode->next == NULL ) ll->tail = newNode;
        }
    }
}    

void display( LL_t *ll )
{
    for ( node_t *current = ll->head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "%d ", current->data );
    }        
    printf( "\n" );
}    

int main( void )
{
    LL_t ll = { NULL, NULL };

    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2 ) spliceinto( &ll, i + 1, i );
    for ( int i = 1; i < 10; i += 2 ) spliceinto( &ll, i + 1, i );

    display( &ll );
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```